# Access-Denied Assistance showing [Data Owner Email] as "none" server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012, access-denied, network-shares

I have Access-Denied Assistance running on my file server.

I have setup a template message

> click Request assistance and an email will be sent to the owner of the
>   folder and your administrator [Admin Email] who will review your
>   request with the folder owner [Data Owner Email]

the folder I am testing has an owner "d.test@test.com" and then users. when I try and access this folder from someone not on the list I get back my message as I expect but it always shows "None" for [Data Owner Email] yet it works for admin email. I am at a bit of a loss. I have tried Google as any good IT admin would but alas I have found nothing. I am really not sure where to look. this is a feature I would like to run for requesting assistance but it's not going to help me if it's not also going to email the owner the folder. sort of defeats the point.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I managed to answer my question with some exploring. What you need to do is setup values for "Folder Owner Email" in "Set Folder Management Properties" in classification properties in the File Server Resource Manager snap in and add values….